# What starts first Application_Start or WebRole's OnStart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I have MVC project on Windows Azure. This project has WebRole with method OnStart. And I want to know what starts first Application_Start of Global.asax or WebRole's OnStart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure this is non-deteministic after SDK 1.3.  Trying to time something from one to the other will just end in a race condition.

Prior to 1.3, the Hosted Worker Core (HWC) was hosted in the RoleEntryPoint, so there was a deterministic startup (OnStart, Application_OnStart, IIRC).  However, with IIS hosting the web now, it is the IISConfigurator.exe that creates the app pool, etc, and eventually w3wp.exe hosts your web site.  This is a different process than your RoleEntryPoint, so either one could start first.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any 100% complete references on this (about the best I've seen is http://blog.syntaxc4.net/?p=271), but I believe the sequence is:

- Any startup tasks are run
- WebRole OnStart method is called
- The WebRole Run() method is called - and at the same time IIS starts the websites - so at this point Application_Start will get called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation, [the Application_Start method is called after the OnStart method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart.aspx)